# Adjective to capture "Tell the gossipers and liars, I'll see them in the fires"

Tags: single-word-requests

In the English language, what adjective can be used to describe the underlying personality of a person saying

> Tell the gossipers and liars, I'll see them in the fires

(Taken from Johnny Cash)

From what I have researched righteous comes close but as the person in question assumes damnation himself (he/she will see them in hell) it is not adequate.

The theme (*I'll see you in hell*) seems fairly common in English literature and/or movies. Usually (but not always) presented with a positive connotation related to a somehow damned hero figure so I assume this is a common concept with an adjective that can be associated with it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Let me try to clarify: The characteristic is the serious or humorous acceptance of own damnation while still carrying out whatever plan it was the person came to fulfill, mixed with a dash of being upbeat about it. The person is not moaning about his own demise but rather accepts and/or welcomes it as a part of proceeding with his plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Devil-may-care.*

Answer (score 0):

George Bernard Shaw fans might call such a person a "[Devil's Disciple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil%27s_Disciple)," after the title character who playfully bestows that moniker on himself:

> JUDITH (angrily). I would rather have a husband whom everybody
>   respects than—than—
>
> RICHARD. Than the devil's disciple. You are right; but I daresay your
>   love helps him to be a good man, just as your hate helps me to be a
>   bad one.

However, that term hasn't made its way into the vernacular as of yet, not officially.

> "*The characteristic is the serious or humorous acceptance of own
>   damnation while still carrying out whatever plan it was the person
>   came to fulfill, mixed with a dash of being upbeat about it*."

Hmmmm... that describes Shaw's Richard Dudgeon to a T.

Answer (score 0):

*Rakehell* (or *rakehelly*) can be used as an adjective meaning profiligate or dissolute. [Dictionary.reference.com definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rakehell?s=t)  Some dictionaries list it as an archaic word, but there is a rock band named "The Rakehells," so it seems to still be in use.

As a noun *rakehell* is a man who is licentious or dissolute.